# git: Объединить две папки в одну (Они в разных ветках)

Tags: git

У меня на гитхабе есть две ветки: `main` и `master`.
На ветке `main` лежит папка `Project`, а на ветке `master` лежит папка `ProjectTest`. У каждой ветки своя история изменений. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы обе папки из обеих веток лежали в одной папке и в одной ветке. 
Иерархия папок должна быть такой: 
`/mainCatalog` 
`----/Project` 
`----/ProjectTest` 
И это должно лежать на одной ветке. Проект и гит мои, поэтому я могу делать всё что понадобится.

Comment: делайте мерж веток

Comment: Можете скопировать папку из одной ветки в другую.
Например, если находитесь в ветке master: `git checkout main <путь до папки в ветке main>`